# Is Holding initaitive possible?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, initiative

Can characters hold their initiative (or simply wait until another acts) in order to coordinate with each other, like to perfectly strike the enemy in sync? Would there be any mechanical benefit from doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, either through Delay or Ready**

> Delay
>
> By choosing to delay, you take no action and then act normally on whatever initiative count you decide to act. When you delay, you voluntarily reduce your own initiative result for the rest of the combat. When your new, lower initiative count comes up later in the same round, you can act normally. You can specify this new initiative result or just wait until some time later in the round and act then, thus fixing your new initiative count at that point.
>
> You never get back the time you spend waiting to see what’s going to happen. You can’t, however, interrupt anyone else’s action (as you can with a readied action).

When you take the Delay special action you basically don't do anything and just wait. You can wait as long as you want and act whenever you want, but you can't interrupt another character's turn.

> Ready
>
> The ready action lets you prepare to take an action later, after your turn is over but before your next one has begun. Readying is a standard action. It does not provoke an attack of opportunity (though the action that you ready might do so).
>
> You can ready a standard action, a move action, or a free action. To do so, specify the action you will take and the conditions under which you will take it. Then, any time before your next action, you may take the readied action in response to that condition. The action occurs just before the action that triggers it. If the triggered action is part of another character’s activities, you interrupt the other character. Assuming he is still capable of doing so, he continues his actions once you complete your readied action. Your initiative result changes. For the rest of the encounter, your initiative result is the count on which you took the readied action, and you act immediately ahead of the character whose action triggered your readied action.
>
> You can take a 5-foot step as part of your readied action, but only if you don’t otherwise move any distance during the round.

When you use a standard action to Ready, you basically set up another action. When whatever trigger you declare happens you perform your action, interrupting the current character's turn. For example you can ready an action to move out of the way when a character casts an AoE spell.

This is most useful when your allies have debuffs or special status that they inflict that you want to take advantage of, but the possibilities are only limited by your tactics.

see the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm) for more details.

Comment: can readied actions be used to move? "When the enemy starts to move, I'll cut off his exit" type of a thing?

Comment: Yup, a move, standard, or free action can all be readied.

Comment: so that means one can't constantly change one's initiative like that, just once per battle?

Comment: No, every time you can use a standard action you can choose ready or delay. You can change your initiative as much as you want, but the cost is not acting for those rounds that you wait.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the game defines two [special initiative actions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm) for this purpose:

- Delay: when your initiative count comes up, you voluntarily decide to lower it, i.e. you let someone else go first. This change is permanent, so if you do this you will go after anyone you let go for the rest of the encounter. The advantage is that you can decide exactly how long to delay (i.e. who to let go first).
- Ready: you declare a standard, move, swift, or free action that you ready, and a condition that will trigger it. This also reduces your initiative so that it matches that of the one who triggered the condition and for the rest of the encounter go just before that character. The advantage here is that you can interrupt another person’s turn.

Comment: Even though you tie, you actually go BEFORE the triggering character's turn on subsequent rounds, regardless of Dex.

Comment: @GreySage Right you are; I thought that was the case but then didn’t see that in the rules and thought I’d been mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mechanics that do what you want: [Readying, and Delaying](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm).

Both of these actions allow characters to manipulate their own initiative order.

As to benefits... Yes, there absolutely are. Both mechanical and narrative. Readying and Delaying both allow one player to "set an enemy up" and then another player to act before that enemy has a chance to recover.

The most basic form of this is "I'll knock him down, and then you kick him before he has a chance to get back up."

Comment: sleep + coup d'Grace's all day long...